# How does QM explain the proton's magnetic moment?

Tags: magnetic-moment

I read that QM is baffled by the proton's angular momentum, I don't know if the issues are related, but do you know if and how it explains the odd value of the magnetic moment of the proton and of the neutron?

Comment: Are you referring to the proton spin crisis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_spin_crisis, or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: The mention of the magnetic moment indicates you're talking about the [anomalous magnetic moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_magnetic_dipole_moment). The Wiki article already contains an overview of how this arises from QFT in the form of higher-order Feynman diagrams. Can you be more specific about what you want to know?

Comment: Very crudely, [yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_magnetic_moment#Magnetic_moment,_quarks,_and_the_Standard_Model), but there are always questions….

Comment: The how is in most good reviews of the quark model, and constituted a crucial argument for its acceptance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note also that the neutron, which has no net charge, nonetheless possesses a magnetic moment- which baffled physicists until such time as it became understood that neither the proton nor the neutron is a fundamental particle- they are made up of quarks which carry fractional amounts of electric charge, and are speeding around inside the proton and neutron.

The (very complicated) internal dynamics of those quarks produces unexpected magnetic effects outside the "particle" which can only be understood via applying QM to the constituent quarks.